# How to reduce LVM size and increase one existing partition's size

Tags: lvm

I want to add 7 GB space to one of my existing partitions (`/dev/xvde1`), and reduce an LVM partition by 7 GB (`/dev/mapper/vg--home-lv--home`). My total disk size is 40 GB.

Detail of partitions is as follows:

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1            7.9G  7.5G   16M 100% /
tmpfs                 1.8G  144K  1.8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/vg--home-lv--home
                       31G   12G   19G  39% /home


# vgdisplay -C
  VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  vg-home   1   1   0 wz--n- 31.00g    0

# pvdisplay -c
  /dev/xvde3:vg-home:65009705:-1:8:8:-1:4096:7935:0:7935:QjUeve-W7W1-fr44-2ENO-3CZy-mIM9-esIdpY

# /etc/fstab
UUID=4f669d3a-76c4-4847-a01d-10df9a96fd8e       /       ext4    grpquota,usrquota,rw    0       1
UUID=bbabd37e-628a-46e8-b384-66654b4c7916 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/vg-home/lv-home    /home   ext4    defaults        0 0
```

Comment: In order to reduce an underlying logical volume size you need to shrink the filesystem on top of it. That depends heavily on the filesystem used, so you might want to add that to your question. Include output of `vgdisplay -C`, `pvdisplay -C` and `lvdisplay -C` as well (these are much more helpful than `df -h` for people who might answer).

Comment: Also add filesystem type, either simply via `df -Th` or include the relevant lines from `/etc/fstab`. This can be done quite simply and  is likely already answered somewhere in SE.

Comment: You should provide an output of `fdisk -l /dev/xvde`. `xvde1` is rootfs, `xvde3` is PV for LVM, and I assume `xvde2` is swap partition and it spreads in between, right?

Comment: Voting to close old question as the required information was never provided.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful!

1. if its ubuntu - set root password
2. reboot and don`t login to system
3. press ctrl+alt+f2 to swith into tty
4. login as root (or login other ssh from over host as root)
5. umount /home
6. resize2fs /dev/vg-home/lv-home 20G (!!!! 20G !!!)
7. lvresize -L21G /dev/vg-home/lv-home     (!!!! 21G !!!)
8. resize2fs /dev/vg-home/lv-home   (without size it resize to maximum - 21G)
9. pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 22G /dev/xvde3
10. resize physical volume:

    ```
    fdisk /dev/xvde
    p ( remember start of /dev/xvde3)
    d
    3
    n
    p
    3
    print value that you remembered
    +23G
    t
    3
    8e
    w
    ```
11. pvresize  /dev/xvde3

Finished!
If you not sure in your skills - don`t start :)

Comment: `lvresize` has an `-r` option to safely resize the filesystem, without worrying about accidentally truncating it.

Comment: This is definitely not all! xvde1,2,3 are DOS type partitions. By the point 10 you just made the `xvde3` smaller (freeing the space at the end of the entire drive). Now you have to move the `xvde3` to the end of the drive, and move the forgotten swap (`xvde2`) partition also. After that the free space will appear between the end of `xvde1` and the beginning of `xvde2`. Now you can perform the `fdisk` routines to enlarge the `xvde1` and finally `resize2fs` on it.

Comment: I would recommend (if it is possible in your env - XEN) booting to `gparted live CD`, it includes all the commands you need + has a graphical partition manipulation - for the moving of partitions it is the best.